# Is there a way to run script conditionally?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm trying to conditionally run a script for a live chat service on one of my clients pages as its annoying to work on the page when the live chat keeps popping up.

I've been trying to accomplish this via the functions.php of my child theme. I decided to use the WP hook "WP_Footer" to inject the script where it would normally load. Unfortunately, when i add my code to the file my site crashes with error "www.hakimlaw.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500".

```
function my_cond_scripts()

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo '<p>Your script will not run here!</p>';
    } else {
        echo '<p>Your script will run here!</p>';
    }
    add_action('wp_footer', 'my_cond_scripts');
```

I was hoping that using echo i could use the web inspector to check if the code is being passed correctly and conditionally. Any input would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Define *"site crashes"* in more technical error related terms. Also nothing in code shown requests a file for a 404 to occur

Comment: My mistake. The error is "www.hakimlaw.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"

Comment: The syntax of your code is off. Start by checking for opening/closing brackets of the function body.

Comment: @EriksKlotins Wow thank you. idk how i missed that!

Comment: @alexyoe, I am moving my comment to an answer. Do you mind approving it as the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP 500 error is caused by a syntax problem in your code. Opening and closing brackets are missing. This should work:

```
function my_cond_scripts()
{
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo '<p>Your script will not run here!</p>';
    } else {
        echo '<p>Your script will run here!</p>';
    }
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'my_cond_scripts');
```